# laravel validation update: It must 'required' only if stored record is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have a filed for validation:

```
public function update(request $request, Sight $sight)
   {
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'img' => 'required|image|max:3000',
         ...
```

It must be 'required',if only 'img' field in stored record is null.

Is it possible?

Comment: sure its possible, you have the model there and you can write conditionals ; you control the string you are assigning to `'img'` there

Comment: Is acceptable for you to use custom validators laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is PHP, it is dynamic. We have conditionals and variables and all that fun jazz.  You control the string that contains all the rules you want to use and you have the model there. Just build your string.

```
public function update(Request $request, Sight $sight)
{
    $required = $sight->img === null ? 'required|' : '';

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'img' => $required .'image|max:30
```

Thats one way without getting into extending anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `required_if` [rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-if)

Ex:

```
// In the following example the field will be required only if the img
// parameter is empty or null
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'img' => 'image|max:3000',
         'field' => 'required_if:img,',
         ...
```

Comment: their condition isn't based on anything in the input or whether another field in the input exists or not

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a validation option called sometimes:

In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the data being validated. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'img' => 'sometimes|required|image|max:30',
]);
```

In the example above, the img field will only be validated if it is present in the $request

#source https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present